# Accessing JSON file from assets in Flex

Tags: json, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

How to decode Json file. 
My code

```
var bytes:ByteArray = new json_file();
var json:String = bytes.readUTFBytes(bytes.length);
var arr:Object = JSON.decode(json);
```

I'm getting the following error when I run the above command

```
Access of undefined property JSON.
-JSON
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code its working for me.

Insted of this code

```
var arr:Object = com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON.decode(json);
```

Use this one

```
var arr:Object = JSON.decode(json);
```

and `import` the below package

```
import com.adobe.serialization.json.JSON;
```